# Karate feature using different ports

Tags: karate

I have feature with multiple scenarios that are building upon each other. Think of it as the first request fetches some data which is then pumped into the second one and so on.

This works fine, as long as all the requests go to the same host. However the last request in the line goes to a different port on the same host, but of course the port which is called from `Karate` is the wrong one.

Here the the `karate-config.js`:

```
function fn() {
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 10000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 10000);

  return {
    tenant: 'ipt',
    bank: 'ndb',
    baseUrl: karate.properties['mws.baseUrl'] ? karate.properties['mws.baseUrl'] : 'http://localhost:8080',
    errorIdentifierMatches: function (actualErrorIdentifier, expectedErrorIdentifier) {
      return actualErrorIdentifier.startsWith(expectedErrorIdentifier);
    },
    sleep: function (millis) {
      karate.log('Sleeping for ' + millis + ' ms');
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(millis)
    },
    generateUUID: function() {
      return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '';
    }
  }
}
```

This results in the last call going to `http://localhost:8080/ipt/registerkey` when it should be `http://localhost:9390/ipt/registerkey`

The relevant part in the feature is defined in the `Background`:

```
  Background:
    Given url baseUrl
    * def s2wKeyExchangeEndpoint = ("/mws/v2/" + tenant + "/" + bank + "/s2w/startkeyexchange")
    * def s2wVerifyAndSignEndpoint = ("/mws/v2/" + tenant + "/" + bank + "/s2w/verifyandsign")
    * def s2wRegisterKey = ("/ipt/registerkey")
```

Is there a way to change the baseUrl from within my feature? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `url` keyword any time in a `Scenario`. It is up to you to manage variables and config.

```
* url 'http://localhost:8080'
* path 'foo', 'bar'
* method get

* url baseUrl
* path 'blah'
* method get
```

So it sounds to me that you have misunderstood the syntax or have over-complicated things.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my confusion. I was under the impression, that `baseUrl` was something that is required by `Karate` in the setup config.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your application stack, but is it possible to test each call in isolation (by using a mock) then perform limited integrated e2e black box tests?